# notify activity that checkbox in listview is clicked

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have an activity that contains listview, inside listview rows i have a checkbox in each row. every time i check or uncheck the checkbox the activity should listen immediately and knows how many rows is checked or unchecked, how do I implement it in android? thanks before

Comment: you can have a button at the end check and uncheck click the button display the toast.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554010/using-checkbox-array-in-android. check this might help. post some code.

Comment: isn't your problem solved yet?

Answer (score 0):

You should create `Listener` like below.

```
interface CheckBoxCleckListener{
    void OnCheckboxClicked();
}
```

Define above code in your adapter class or other.

Now whenever you want to call it, write following code in your Adapter class.

```
//this will create object of listener
public static CheckBoxCleckListener checkBoxCleckListener;
```

You need to initialized it by your caller class which is your Activity in your case.

```
public static void addListener(
    CheckBoxCleckListener listener) {
    checkBoxCleckListener= listener;
}
```

Now, whenever your check box clicked, write following code inside,

```
checkBoxCleckListener.OnCheckboxClicked();
```

In your activity class, write following code,

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements CheckBoxCleckListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          //rest of code
          YOUR_CLASS_WHERE_INTERFACE_IMPLEMENTED.addListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void OnCheckboxClicked() {
        //do your coding
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Chintan, is there any way we avoid using static method?

Comment: um.. yes. If you have created "Adapter" class and create object of that, then before using it, with that object you can register your listener. :)